# Any existing OpenID Connect Identity Provider Implementations on App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid-connect, openid-provider

I'm researching OpenID Connect Identity Providers (IDP) in anticipation of building one on Google App Engine in Java.

Do any implementations already exist that I can examine or use?

To be clear, I am *not* authenticating with Google Sign-On, this will be a custom method of authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for it as well!